# Can YOLOV5​ output string data?

Tags: yolov5

I'm working on my school project about object detection but we stuck on how can we make our model output string data not an image. Is it even possible to make a model that output string data using YOLOV5? By the way, we tried using other YOLO before but we seem to cannot make it work out, we can only use YOLOV5. Is there a way for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's possible from the cmd, an argument of detect.py it's "--save-txt". It's gonna save a file .txt of the inference.